# Spring Framework Error creating bean with name and No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm starting on Spring Framework and have some problems: After I changed the packages structure for my `@Service`, `@Controller`, `@Entity` and `@Repository` classes my project stopped working. Before the change my project was running correctly, and now I do not know why it wont start up.

The package structure was something like:

- `com.sandbox.config`
- `com.sandbox.service`
- `com.sandbox.service.impl`
- `com.sandbox.controllers`
- `com.sandbox.dao`
- `com.sandbox.dao.impl`
- `com.sandbox.entities`

And I changed to:

- `com.sandbox.config`
- `com.sandbox.business.service`
- `com.sandbox.business.service.impl`
- `com.sandbox.frontend.controllers`
- `com.sandbox.persistency.dao`
- `com.sandbox.persistency.dao.impl`
- `com.sandbox.persistency.entities`

My configuration classes are:

**SpringJdbcConfig:**

```
package com.sandbox.config;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sandbox.*" })
public class SpringJdbcConfig {...}
```

**WebConfig:**

```
package com.sandbox.config;
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sandbox.*" })
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {...}
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?
I am getting these errors at the eclipse output console:

1. `Error creating bean with name 'staffServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'staffDao'.`
2. `No qualifying bean of type 'com.sandbox.persistency.dao.StaffDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate`.

And I receive the same errors for each class of my project.

Comment: Maybe try a clean and build?

Comment: can you post the code of `StaffDao` and `StaffServiceImpl` classes

Comment: I tried clean and build, also I used purge maven dependencies command. The code of the classes are: `@Repository
public class StaffDaoImpl implements StaffDao {...}` and `@Service
public class StaffServiceImpl implements StaffService {`

Answer (score 0):

Change `ComponentScan` as below and try again:

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.sandbox.business.service","com.sandbox.persistency.dao" })
```

Comment: Nop, it doesn't work, I'am still getting the same errors. For example: `Error creating bean with name 'actorServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'actorDao'` for all classes in my project.

Answer (score 0):

after hours searching and testing I found the solution to my problem. If I change the package structure adding a new package level, **Spring duplicates Bean classes** if `@ComponentScan` is used **more than one time**. That doesn't happen if You keep all packages at the same level. In my case I was using `@ComponentScan` in classes `SpringJdbcConfig` and `WebConfig`.

I had it set up like this:

**SpringJdbcConfig:**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sandbox.*" })
public class SpringJdbcConfig {...}
```

**WebConfig:**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sandbox.*" })
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {...}
```

And I changed it to:

**SpringJdbcConfig:**

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.sandbox.config", "com.sandbox.persistency.*" })
public class SpringJdbcConfig {...}
```

**WebConfig:**

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.sandbox.config", "com.sandbox.business.*", "com.sandbox.persistency.*", "com.sandbox.frontend.*" })
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {...}
```

I hope it helps. :)